# Can a gem install take an hour or more?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm trying to install the spree_social extension and all of its dependencies and when I run bundler its just saying resolving dependencies... for a really long time. There are a lot of them but that just seems like its too long.

Here's a list of dependencies: 
    https://gemnasium.com/spree/spree_social

I just put gem "spree_social" in the gemfile and bundled. And when I try to run the instructions on github:

```
gem "spree_social", :git => "git://github.com/spree/spree_social.git"
```

I get:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'spree_core (~> 2.0.0.beta) ruby', which is required by gem 'spree_social (>= 0) ruby', in any of the sources.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar (not sure if it's the same) issue with another project, so [this file](https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor/blob/master/Gemfile.rails_version) was added to address it.

Basically, by not checking the Rails version, for this gem, in this case, the dependency resolution would take a really long time, potentially hours/days/years (I don't think any of the affected users ever waited for it overnight), though it should eventually finish.

I didn't write that file, but I think the crux of the issue is that it helps bundler narrow down all the possible versions that could be installed, speeding up the process in this case. I think this dependency resolution taking forever issue tends to be project specific.

This isn't a full answer in terms of giving you a clear answer to the "why" this is happening, but it may point you in the right direction or at least to something that will help uncover what's happening.